# How can you add data-toggle="dropdown" to an anchor

Tags: jquery

So I have an anchor which looks like

```
<a href="http://something.com/something/" class="dropdown-toggle">something</a>
```

and I want to add

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
```

so that it ends up looking like

```
<a href="http://something.com/something/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">something</a>
```

I tried

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").data("toggle", "dropdown");
```

But it isnt adding anything
cheers

Comment: After you've done `$(".dropdown-toggle").data("toggle", "dropdown");` go to the console and enter `console.log($(".dropdown-toggle").data("toggle"));`  Not seeing it and not working are two different things ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) jquery method to add the attribute.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8xnFh/)**

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
```

Comment: what if I want to add another attribute in addition to this? Can we call another attr just after first attr call or we have to wrap everything in json? If we have to wrap in json, what would json look like? For example, what if I want to add data-target as additional attribute? (Sorry for asking so late but I have just started learning jquery)